# Getting out the value of a key in multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, jsondecoder

In my php query I got this output:

```
{"projects":[{"id":127,"name":"efrat","status":{"id":10,"name":"development","label":"development"},"description":"","enabled":true,"view_state":{"id":10,"name":"public","label":"public"},"access_level":{"id":90,"name":"administrator","label":"administrator"},"custom_fields":[{"id":1,"name":"Customer email","type":"email","default_value":"","possible_values":"","valid_regexp":"","length_min":0,"length_max":50,"access_level_r":{"id":10,"name":"viewer","label":"viewer"},"access_level_rw":{"id":10,"name":"viewer","label":"viewer"},"display_report":true,"display_update":true,"display_resolved":true,"display_closed":true,"require_report":false,"require_update":false,"require_resolved":false,"require_closed":false}],"versions":[],"categories":[{"id":93,"name":"Monitor","project":{"id":0,"name":null}},{"id":31,"name":"Proactive","project":{"id":0,"name":null}},{"id":30,"name":"Project","project":{"id":0,"name":null}},{"id":29,"name":"Support","project":{"id":0,"name":null}}]}]}
```

after using 'json_decode' method on it, I get this:
"(

```
[projects] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 127
                [name] => myprojectname
                [status] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 10
                        [name] => development
                        [label] => development
                    )

                [description] =>
                [enabled] => 1
                [view_state] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 10
                        [name] => public
                        [label] => public
                    )

                [access_level] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 90
                        [name] => administrator
                        [label] => administrator
                    )

                [custom_fields] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [name] => Customer email
                                [type] => email
                                [default_value] =>
                                [possible_values] =>
                                [valid_regexp] =>
                                [length_min] => 0
                                [length_max] => 50
                                [access_level_r] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 10
                                        [name] => viewer
                                        [label] => viewer
                                    )

                                [access_level_rw] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 10
                                        [name] => viewer
                                        [label] => viewer
                                    )

                                [display_report] => 1
                                [display_update] => 1
                                [display_resolved] => 1
                                [display_closed] => 1
                                [require_report] =>
                                [require_update] =>
                                [require_resolved] =>
                                [require_closed] =>
                            )

                    )

                [versions] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [categories] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 93
                                [name] => Monitor
                                [project] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 0
                                        [name] =>
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 31
                                [name] => Proactive
                                [project] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 0
                                        [name] =>
                                    )

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 30
                                [name] => Project
                                [project] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 0
                                        [name] =>
                                    )

                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 29
                                [name] => Support
                                [project] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 0
                                        [name] =>
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)"

In my PHP, how can I release the "name" object value (the result should be 'myprojectname') from this array? I've tried many foreach loops that got me nowhere.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have one object, that when decoded actually only has one array item. So, in your case, ‘myprojectname’ may simply be “$projects[0][‘name’]”

If many array items, you could

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
  echo $project[‘name’];
}
```

**EDIT**: I took object provided and json_decoded it myself, it doesn't match the json_decoded item presented by OP -- the first image shows the code to var_dump 'name' OP desired, part of the code also below:

```
$decoded = json_decode($obj);
$projects = $decoded->projects;
$name = $projects[0]->name;
```

[image: the parsing presented here outputs the 'name' requested by OP]
[image: the var_dump]

Comment: I'm also guessing its actualy one array with nested arrays in it. When I try you'r suggestion it I get: " PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name"

Comment: okay, so I took your exact output -- 'myprojectname' isn't there once i json_decode it

Comment: thank you, now it works, I think my problem was using "$projects=json_decode($result, true);", when I changed it to be "$projects=json_decode($result);" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'projects' contains an array (`"projects":[{"id":127, ... }]`). I assume that the 'projects'-array might contain multiple 'project'-objects like this?

```
{
    "projects":
    [
        {
            "id":127,
            "name":"my-project"
        },
        {
            "id":128,
            "name":"my-other-project"
        }
    ]
}
```

In that case you need the arrow notation to access the name property, for example:

```
foreach ($projects as $project_object) {
    foreach ($project_object as $project) {
        echo $project->name . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I took a minimal code example of the OP and got the expected result:

[image]

Can you add more details in your code snippets in your original question or provide us with a working example of your code? 
There are some online PHP sandboxes that can help you with this. For example: I stripped out all code that does not seem related to your question and got the result you are looking for in two different ways: 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/009c53671fd9545e4fcecfe4b0328974381ee2ce

It is also a good idea to sum up all the foreach loops that you already tried, so we can see if you were nearly there with your own solution. This way we can understand your question better and it prevents us from offering solutions that you already used.

Comment: projects array contains multiple arrays all related to this one project. when I try this foreach loop I get this error: "PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: It is not very clear to me if there might be multiple _arrays_ or multiple _objects_ in "projects", so I will base my view on your first code example now. Can you try two more foreach loops? One looks like this and is based on Kat's earlier answer -> `foreach($projects as $project) { 
    echo $project[0]['name'];
}`


The other is a combination of Kat's approach and mine -> `foreach($projects as $project) { 
    echo $project[0]->name;
}`

Comment: Thank you, I will keep in mind your idea for next time. I also used the php sandbox you used, I edited the $raw to match my case and as you can see I can't make it work like you did, since, I think, I added one more layer in the array. can you take a look at this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fad5417031221bb68e6141e0e9a3b95e0626aa7

Comment: You're welcome. I see in your last sandbox link that you have put the wrong raw data in the variable `$raw`, json_decode can not accept the second code snippet you have in your original question/post. The json_decode function will see that as invalid JSON and will return NULL. It can perfectly decode your first code snippet like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9666ce8fa8518e0778a549941a134fded3282768
I think you're doing something extra or your json_decode is not correct, because you shouldn't have that raw output you showed in your sandbox link.

Comment: The string you have put in `$raw` looks like a print_r to me. First you need to put the correct JSON in that variable, then the json_decode can process that correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much @Virginia, it works. First you are right I mixed it up a bit in my last snippet, I set $raw with the json and not with the raw data. But the thing that did the difference for me, I think, is when I changed it from '$projects = json_decode($result, true);' to just '$projects = json_decode($result);' . now it works, thanks again.